# unable to startActivity(context, intent) from BroadcastReceiver Class in API R (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

*(Before you mark this question duplicate, please note that I'm facing this problem in a specific API Level (API R), the app shows normal expected working behaviour on other API levels below R).*

**When running the app on Pixed 3a `API R`**
I'm trying out the the Alarm Manager in android, by building a basic Alarm app. I have an AlarmPageActivity that I tried to start from my custom Broadcast Receiver (`AlarmReceiver.java`)
I have code in my MainActivity where I set the alarm using Alarm Manager. When the alarm goes off, the pending intent goes to the `AlarmReceiver` class where I try to start an activity using `context.startActivity(context, alarmIntent)`.

**The problem:** *[Before you go there, yes I have the appropriate flags required (`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`)]*. When I set a time for the alarm, and keep the app open, the AlarmPageActivity (the activity which is supposed to pop open when the alarm goes off) launches and the app executes normal behaviour. But when I set a time, and close the app (`onDestroy()`), the code follows through to `AlarmReceiver.java` (my Broadcast receiver), the ringtone starts playing, but my AlarmPageActivity doesn't show up (In fact, even it's `onCreate()` method does not execute). Neither does it show any error in the Log/run window. I tried changing everything from pending intent parameters, to adding new activity flags to the intent object, etc. but ***nothing worked!*** You can see below in the code that there is no syntax error that should be stopping the code from starting a new activity through broadcast receiver (when the user is outside the app).

I faced this issue for nearly 2 days. I read every article/post on the internet about starting an activity from a broadcast receiver class. But it wouldn't work, and I got so frustrated. Then **MIRACULOUSLY**, I thought why not try running the app on a different emulator. And guess what? **it worked.** `sigh...` I kept thinking I was doing something wrong or that my code was whack because I'm only so beginner-ish in android studio. But little did I know, that my code was correct all that time.

**When running the app on Pixed 3a `API 26`**
The app shows normal expected behaviour. Even after onDestroy(), the BroadCast receiver receives and launches the AlarmPageActivity, *with the ringtone* :)

**My Question:** This is the same code (I didn't change/add anything else) that was not working on the emulator device running API R, but works now in API 26. Can somebody explain why it wouldn't work? I would really appreciate. Or maybe my code wasn't compatible with API R in some way... who knows? Enlighten me!

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...
    other code...
    ...

    // Alarm manager code ----------------------------------------
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            alarmIntent, 0);

    alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, alarmPendingIntent);
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    Log.d("asdfasdf", "BroadcastReceiver (alarmReceiver) activity reached");

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AlarmPageActivity.class);

    alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(alarmIntent);

    alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    // ringtone code ...
    ringtone.play();

    Log.d("asdfasdf", "Reached end of alarmReceiver "); 
}
} // mind the wrong indenting here
```

**AlarmPageActivity.java**

```
has the default empty activity code...
```

*And yes, I know I shouldn't run an activity from a Broadcast receiver as it shouldn't do heavy task that takes > 10s and everything, but I just wanted to see how to it would look like before improving on that code later.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it not work from android 10 and higher. Please read more detail about [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts). Try to request permisison `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` for this case

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right! I didn't know about his documentation, but I assure you thats a precious link! I think it has everything I need to tackle this issue. Thanks a lot! @Công Hai

Comment: How you fix this. I have the same problem. My app also has broadcast receiver which will start an activity. The activity starts in lower android apis, But it is not working in android 11. Please help. Thank you!